# Showing Textbox ToolTip

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tooltip

I am trying to work in the tooltip in vb.net. What I am trying to do is whatever I  write the text in the textbox control show it in the tooltip. I am able to show text in tooltip but my question is when I edit input text it will show old and new text in the popup tooltip. Here is what I have done so far.

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim s As String = ""

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    s = TextBox1.Text
    Dim tooltip1 As System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip()

    tooltip1.SetToolTip(Button1, s)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to figure out why this is useful, but try using the `TextChanged` event of the textbox to update the tooltip:

```
Private _ToolTip As New ToolTip()

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                 Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
  _ToolTip.Show(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Better

Private _ToolTip As New ToolTip()

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles TextBox1.MouseHover

_ToolTip.Show(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1)

End Sub