# TextBox string as tooltip on hover

Tags: vb.net, hover, tooltip

I'm building an application and I have a `TextBox` control that is filled with a value. On some occasions the control is too small and I don't have the space to expand it.

How do you show the `TextBox` content on hover when the control is too small?

Comment: are we talking about WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP .NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing Textbox ToolTip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543318/showing-textbox-tooltip)

Comment: Try the following link. If you only want the tool tip to show for certain values then add an if condition for the text box. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168550/display-a-tooltip-over-a-button-using-windows-forms

Answer (score 2):

Add a tooltip to the form and the following code

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseHover
    ToolTip1.SetToolTip(TextBox1, TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This has the same answer as this question:
[Showing Textbox ToolTip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543318/showing-textbox-tooltip)

```
Private _toolTip As New ToolTip()

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
                                 Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
  _toolTip.Show(TextBox1.Text, TextBox1)
End Sub
```