# set tooltip text to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, text, tooltip

**Picture:**

[image: very nice picture]

[image: Tooltip]

[image: Breakpoint]

I want my tooltip to show the text that is set in a textbox, how can I do this exactly? Yes I know the Tooltip property but textbox.Text does not work, I just want to show textbox text in tooltip (dynamic).

Thanks for your help

Comment: when is the tooltip supposed to be shown? when hoovering over the textbox with the mouse cursor?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: @Lucas I fixed the problem and tried it in my own project it should work now.

Comment: if it solves  your problem please mark it as the solution so others won't attempt to write an answer even tough the problem is solved and delete your answer with just 2 pictures in it (I added them to your question already)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the Tooltip each time the TextBoxText has changed you can put the `SetToolTip()` Function into the [`OnTextChanged()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=netcore-3.1) Callback.

```cs
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    toolTip1.ShowAlways = true;
    toolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "TextBox Text";
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, textBox1.Text);
}

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, textBox1.Text);
}
```

To add the TextChanged Event you need to open the TextBoxs Property page, click on the Thunderbolt and add the Function Name to the TextChanged Row.

[image: TextChanged]

Comment: no look i just want a tooltip when i hover over the textbox, tooltip text has to be the same as textbox's

Comment: i tried what you suggested but it\s not showing, i added a new tooltip to designer too

Comment: ok.. now how can i show it. toolTip1.Show() or toolTip.ShowAlways = true ?

Comment: Error  The name 'e' does not exist in the current context

Comment: what did you fix? still not working for me btw i use TextChanged, i dont know if theres a difference dont think so

Comment: nah that's just the name that should be fine, I changed the `OnTextChanged` Function

Comment: oh yes i see i use the newest function now. but still same error: 'e' does not exist in current context
does it work for you?

Comment: its kinda like this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244139/textbox-string-as-tooltip-on-hover but it's in vb code..... :/

Comment: Nope unfortunately not working. did you assign the tooltip to the textbox or something? wait i will add another picture

Answer (score 0):

Picture of textbox property window.

[property window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/961Cf.png)

[breakpoint etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPmf3.png)

Comment: why microsoft makes it so hard to do this, why isnt it so simple like tooltip.text = textbox.text omg

Comment: I tried the code in my own test project now and i changed it. It should work now.